# Как по-русски называют такие конструкции?

Tags: синтаксис

Это какой-то специальный уступочный оборот или предложение с составе другого предложения?

"Любое благо, **откуда бы оно ни исходило**, исходит от Святого Духа."

Comment: Обобщённо-уступительный оборот, похоже.

Comment: мне еще интересно: 
глагол "исходило" - он стоит в сослагательном наклонении или это простое прошедшее время?

Comment: Голосую за сослагательное.  Можно ведь сказать "одкуда оно ни исходит", убрав "бы" и изменив форму глагола, тогда не сослагательное...

Comment: точно, согласна! спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 3):

> "Любое благо, **откуда бы оно ни исходило**, исходит от Святого Духа."

Выделенное жирным -- придаточное уступительное. Основа -- *"оно исходило"*; *"откуда бы ни"* -- наречие в знач. союзного слова, в предложении явл. обстоятельством.

Answer (score 1):

С моей точки зрения, эта конструкция представляет собой придаточное предложение, стоящее внутри всего сложного предложения. Схема: (...,[откуда бы],...).